# rsnapshot - Differential/incrimental

Tags: rsnapshot

I've just set up rsnapshot to backup some files to my FS and it seems to be working well. I was wondering if the system does differential/incremental backups by default or do i need to configure it? 
I'm backup up a nextcloud install so I would ideally only like to backup the changed files to save space on the remote server.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of `rsnapshot` is that it uses `rsync` to send the files, which only sends changed files, and even only the parts of those files that have changed, and that it hard links files that are entirely unchanged to the previous backup so they take up no more disk space, even though it appears that you have a separate directory for each backup that has everything in it.

Comment: Thanks, I'm backup up to a network share on a windows server. Will this break the functionality?